# A curious exercise in Spivak's book on calculus

Tags: calculus, reference-request, physics, reference-works

On chapter 9 of the said book there is an exercise in which Spivak asks the reader to prove that Galileo "got his facts wrong". More specifically, Spivak asks one to to show if a body falls a distance $d(t)$ in $t$ second and $d^{\prime}$ is proportional to $d$ then $d$ cannot be a function of the form $d(t) = ct^{2}$.

Settling it is kind of a no-brainer: yet, did Galileo really claim what Spivak is attributing to him therein? Do you know if this "mistake" by Galileo had been noticed before? If I understand correctly, even Newton took for granted the claim by Galileo according to which "the descent of bodies varied as the square of the time" (cf. p. 21 of vol. I of the University of California Press edition of the *Principia*)? What's going on here?

Let me thank you for your comments, suggestions, links, answers, etc.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the full question (perhaps a screenshot).

Comment: Better asked in the history of math and science stack exchange.

Comment: @littleO You can see it [here](https://books.google.pt/books?id=7JKVu_9InRUC&pg=PA162#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I cannot see it. The page is not available to me.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I don't why. I suppose that I have no privilege concerning that website.

Comment: @littleO: What you read in the first paragraph of my question is basically it... There are two more items to the exercise, but this is the controversial one.

Comment: For a full book on this subject, see: Peter Damerow, ‎Gideon Freudenthal, ‎Peter McLaughlin, J.Renn [Exploring the Limits of Preclassical Mechanics: A Study of Conceptual Development in Early Modern Science: Free Fall and Compounded Motion in the Work of Descartes, Galileo and Beeckman](https://books.google.it/books?id=vmPaBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Galileo made that error (and so did Descartes). I suggest that you read *The new science of motion: A study of Galileo's De motu locali*, by Winifred L. Wisan (Archive for History of Exact Sciences, June 1974, **13**, Issue 2–3, pp 103–306).

Comment: Can you state explicitly what the error was?  Did Galileo believe that the acceleration of a falling object is proportional to its velocity?

Comment: @littleO He and Descartes believed that the speed of a body moving in free fall was proportional to the distance already covered. Later, Galileo understood  that it is proportional to the time ellapsed.